# Expressions and equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Murphy's love to have parties. Last Friday, they gave a party and the doorbell rang 15 times. At the first ring, one guest arrived. Each time the doorbell rang after that, two more guests arrived than the time before.
On Saturday they had another party. At the first ring of the doorbell a single guest arrived, at the second ring two guests appeared, at the third ring three guests and so on. If the doorbell rang 20 times Saturday night, how many guests attended? Was this party bigger than Friday's? How do you know? Write an equation for each night and solve.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Write it as $$\sum_{n=0}^{14}1+2n$$ for Friday and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{19}1+n$$ for Saturday.